# Forcing a Specific Import Path in Go

Tags: go

New Go programmer here -- apologies if this is well worn territory, but my google searching hasn't turned up the answer I'm looking for.

Short Version: Can I, as a programmer external to the core Go project, force my packages to be imported with a specific name.  If so, how?

Long Version: I recently tried to install the `bcrypt` package from the [following GitHub repository](https://github.com/golang/crypto/), with the following `go get`

```
go get github.com/golang/crypto
```

The package downloaded correctly into my workspace, but when I tried to import it, I got the following error

> $ go run main.go main.go:10:2: code in directory /path/to/go/src/github.com/golang/crypto/bcrypt expects import "golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt"

i.e. something told Go this package was supposed to be imported with `golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt`.  This tipped me off that what I actually wanted was

```
go get golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt
```

I'd like to do something similar in my own packages — is this functionality built into Go packaging?  Or are the authors of `crypto/bcrypt` doing something at runtime to detect and reject invalid package import names?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it's built in, I can't seem to find the implementation document (it's a relatively new feature in 1.5 or 1.6) however the syntax is:

```
package name // import "your-custom-path"
```

Example: https://github.com/golang/crypto/blob/master/bcrypt/bcrypt.go#L7

// edit

The design document for this feature is https://docs.google.com/document/d/1jVFkZTcYbNLaTxXD9OcGfn7vYv5hWtPx9--lTx1gPMs/edit

// edit

@JimB pointed out to https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Import_path_checking, and in the go1.4 release notes: https://golang.org/doc/go1.4#canonicalimports

Comment: https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Import_path_checking, and in the go1.4 release notes: https://golang.org/doc/go1.4#canonicalimports

Comment: @JimB coulda swore I checked that, I'll add it to the post for better clarity.