# What is the purpose of the commented import statement after the package statement?

Tags: go

Some packages have a commented import statement just after the package statement. An example is visible [here](https://github.com/golang/freetype/blob/master/truetype/truetype.go).

```
. . .
package truetype // import "github.com/golang/freetype/truetype"
. . .
```

It seam that this appears on a package inside a module. Not all files of the package have this comment.

What is the purpose of this comment ? Why is it there ?

I didn’t find anything about this in the go specification.

Comment: This defines under which import path the package must be imported.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37330303/13860

Comment: @blackgreen: But the fact that it can be confused with documentation is a great reason that I dislike Go's various comment-based tricks.

Comment: @Volker It seam that this has become obsolete since we use go.mod. Can I thus ignore it ? Is it replaced by the module name in the go.mod file ?

Comment: @chmike: it is redundant now with `go.mod`, and no longer needed

Comment: It might be redundant if the given import path actually matches the one from go.mod but if not I do not know if your build will succeed. Did you try it out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is for custom import paths.

See the [import path checking](https://golang.org/pkg/cmd/go/#hdr-Import_path_checking) documentation, and also [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46313408/8206).

> A package statement is said to have an "import comment" if it is
> immediately followed (before the next newline) by a comment of one of
> these two forms:
>
> ```
> package math // import "path"
> package math /* import "path" */
> ```
>
> The go command will refuse to install a package with an import comment
> unless it is being referred to by that import path. In this way,
> import comments let package authors make sure the custom import path
> is used and not a direct path to the underlying code hosting site.

Comment: It might be useful to add that it has become obsolete with the usage of go modules.